# set umask (permissions) similarly as setgid on a directory

Tags: permissions, directory, umask, setuid

I know how to use `setgid` on directories, to enforce that whole directory structure has uniform `user:group` ownership.

Is there a similar way to set the `umask` for a directory, so that the whole directory structure "inherits" specific permissions (i.e. `750/640`)?

Comment: No, umasks aren't attached to directories, they're attached to a process. http://askubuntu.com/questions/44534/how-to-set-umask-for-a-specific-folder. Setting a ACL (using setfacl) might be a way though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is ugly hack to apply on directory.

```
mount -o loop,umask=027,uid=test /opt/dev_test /home/test/test2
```

Since `umask` on mount point applied on NTFS or VFAT  partition, I had created block device using `dd` command then formatted with `mkfs.vfat` and mounted with command as mentioned above.

**Test Result**

Inside `test2` directory

```
[test@test-server test2]$ touch xyz
[test@test-server test2]$ ls -rlt xyz
-rwxr-x--- 1 test root 0 Jan 28 23:22 xyz
[test@test-server test2]$ umask
0002
```

Outside `test2` directory

```
[test@test-server test2]$ cd ../
[test@test-server ~]$ touch xyz
[test@test-server ~]$ ls -rlt xyz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 test test 0 Jan 28 23:22 xyz
[test@test-server ~]$ umask
0002
```

Answer (score 1):

The `umask` value for the process that creates a file or a directory will control the ultimate specific permissions at the time the process executes.  By convention (default), files are created with a creation mode (to `open()`) of 0666 while directories are created with 0777.  The `umask` value is then factored in to establish the final permissions.

Thus, your "best" choice is to make sure that processes that manipulate the particular directory use a `umask` of 0027 while will provide directories with 0750 and files with 0640.